trips VS a set in poker
What is the difference between trips and a set?
I'm quite new to poker, and I've noticed that sometimes players refers to a "Three of a kind" ranked hand as "trips" and sometimes as "a set".
Is this culture related?

Used in community card games, both trips and sets are representative of the same hand strength (i.e. Three of a Kind), but trips are achieved by having two same ranked community cards and by holding a third copy, and sets are achieved by having two same ranked cards in your hand, and the third copy is found in the community cards.
For example, in Omaha, if you have AQ33 and the board comes AA587, then you have trips, but if the board comes 43287, you have a set.

What is it called if the 3 of a kind is on the board? What is four of a kind with two of the same ranked cards in hand? A superset?
